# Understanding method of applying modes on chords

Tags: theory, electric-guitar, chord-progressions, modes

I am learning about modes and trying to apply them on guitar over chord progressions, and I wanted to understand how exactly to know, when you hear some song, "ah, this song allows me to play Dorian in A over it, or Mixolydian in G over it", etc.

I found a [method of determining this here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Guitar/comments/1t0gyg/modes_are_often_a_question_on_rguitar_so_i_tried/), quote:

> In the son.g Oye Como Va by Santana, we have the following chords: A
> Minor - D7 If you look at the Harmonized Major Scale, you'll see that
> this corresponds to a: ii - V, in the key of G Major. Since we're
> playing the G Major scale over a chord progression that's tonal center
> is A Minor, we know we are playing in A Dorian (The 2nd mode of G
> major is A Dorian).

Having this information, I tried to practice it, by applying it to other songs. I took for example "Fly Away" by Lenny Kravitz. The song has the chord progression:

A C G D

To my ears, it sounds like I should be focusing on the start of the progression which is **A and C**, since **A** sounds as tonal center of the progression (to my ears at least). So I opened up [Harmonized Major Scale chart](https://guitarendeavor.com/harmonizing-major-scale-guitar/):

...and here is where I am stuck. If I look at the chart, the combination of A and C appears at:

- option A) "I III" in A, this would give A Ionian (?)
- option B) "II VII" in B, this means A Locrian (?)
- option C) "V VII" in D, so A Mixolydian (?)
- option D) "II IV" in G, so A Dorian.

I tried these assumptions and the **A Dorian** sounded *really good* (to my ears, subjective) on Fly Away. And this is where I get confused, because I feel like I chose the option totally randomly based on just occurrences in the harmonized major scale chart. So I guess the correct answer was: option D) with A Dorian, but why not the others too? Why are the other options wrong, did I misunderstood the method of identifying the right mode?

How do you know *really know* a mode fits in some key, when you see a chord progression?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may well be perceived as a dupe - there are already lots of similar questions on this site.

However - you consider A Dorian. Let's look at the notes from A dorian. A B C D E F♯ G. The chords for the song are A C G and D. There's certainly a 1 and 3 from each of those chords in the whole mode - C&E, G&B, D&F♯, but it doesn't bode so well for the A- A&C gives Am. Which usually sounds fine in a Bluesy way over A major, so 'it works'.

You consider A Locrian - A B♭ C D E♭ F G. Lots of clashes there, but with Locrian, that's par for the course!(Read later).

You also consider A Mixolydian - A B C♯ D E F♯ G. Some clashes there too.

When a piece has only diatonic chords/notes it is easier to use one scale - the diatonic of that key. However, when a set of chords is *not* diatonic - A C G D is one example - then it'll be a sort of compromise to use one mode throughout. Better, maybe, to play with the changes. By using notes which work with a chord and the following chord, the transition can sound very smooth. Example: finish the A bar on an E note, and that could even be tied to the first part of the C bar.

And, as an aside - your Locrian isn't right. A Locrian has the parent key of B♭.

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with Tim above. In case a helper sheet may be of use, here is my mine listing the modes, keys and chords. HTH - catz
[image: Modes/Keys/Chords sheet]